# How to find the onclick field using firefinder?

Tags: selenium, firebug

I have the following HTML snippet,

```
<a onclick="courseOfferingClose(); return false;" href="">
    Close
</a>
```

In this snippet, I'm trying to find the `onclick` field using firebug [firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/). I have tried the following,

```
[onclick*='courseOfferingClose'] 

a[contains(@onclick,'courseOfferingClose')]

[contains(@onclick,'courseOfferingClose')]
```

But none of these work... Any ideas please

Comment: HTML IS:
<a onclick="courseOfferingClose('http://sls355.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com:81/LMS1324/lms?

Role=Trainingadmin&amp;Action=TACrsVwAdd&amp;CrsId=50D120524153208B8C25135700019F1F&amp;Prices=&amp;Is

OnlineOfferingAdded=true'); return false;" href="" onmouseover="this.style.color='#ff0000'" 

onmouseout="this.style.color=''" style="">Close</a>

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might benefit from [code formatting in SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), and it looks like your title is incomplete - what is it that you're trying to find? Lastly, your comment looks like you're wanting to edit your question, do you know that you can edit the question directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try css-selector,

```
a[onclick*='courseOfferingClose']
```

or Xpath,

```
//a[contains(@onclick, 'courseOfferingClose')]
```